SSL error with salesforce API using requests library in python
I've recently run into a problem trying to connect to the salesforce API using python simple-salesforce and requests library to download some data for some PowerBI and analytics applications / forecasting / machine learning apps.
I'm on python 3.10.4 on Windows 10 and have the latest updated to latest published version of requests and simple-salesforce.
The error I'm getting is SSL failed self certify. The bit that's throwing me off is I have another pipeline in golang that is working fine on the same machine. I've been able to implement a workaround by setting the verify=False on the session and passing this through to requests. I'm also able to get a response from the server using the lower level urllib3 to make to same request which is working fine.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:466, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
    465 try:
--> 466     self._validate_conn(conn)
    467 except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1095, in HTTPSConnectionPool._validate_conn(self, conn)
   1094 if conn.is_closed:
-> 1095     conn.connect()
   1097 # TODO revise this, see https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2791

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py:730, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
    728 server_hostname_rm_dot = server_hostname.rstrip(".")
--> 730 sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
    731     sock=sock,
    732     cert_reqs=self.cert_reqs,
    733     ssl_version=self.ssl_version,
    734     ssl_minimum_version=self.ssl_minimum_version,
    735     ssl_maximum_version=self.ssl_maximum_version,
    736     ca_certs=self.ca_certs,
    737     ca_cert_dir=self.ca_cert_dir,
    738     ca_cert_data=self.ca_cert_data,
    739     cert_file=self.cert_file,
    740     key_file=self.key_file,
    741     key_password=self.key_password,
    742     server_hostname=server_hostname_rm_dot,
    743     ssl_context=self.ssl_context,
    744     tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
    745     assert_hostname=self.assert_hostname,
    746     assert_fingerprint=self.assert_fingerprint,
    747 )
    748 self.sock = sock_and_verified.socket

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py:909, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(sock, cert_reqs, ssl_version, ssl_minimum_version, ssl_maximum_version, cert_file, key_file, key_password, ca_certs, ca_cert_dir, ca_cert_data, assert_hostname, assert_fingerprint, server_hostname, ssl_context, tls_in_tls)
    907         server_hostname = normalized
--> 909 ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
    910     sock=sock,
    911     keyfile=key_file,
    912     certfile=cert_file,
    913     key_password=key_password,
    914     ca_certs=ca_certs,
    915     ca_cert_dir=ca_cert_dir,
    916     ca_cert_data=ca_cert_data,
    917     server_hostname=server_hostname,
    918     ssl_context=context,
    919     tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
    920 )
    922 try:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:469, in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data, tls_in_tls)
    467 context.set_alpn_protocols(ALPN_PROTOCOLS)
--> 469 ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    470 return ssl_sock

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, ssl_context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    511     return SSLTransport(sock, ssl_context, server_hostname)
--> 513 return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py:512, in SSLContext.wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    506 def wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side=False,
    507                 do_handshake_on_connect=True,
    508                 suppress_ragged_eofs=True,
    509                 server_hostname=None, session=None):
    510     # SSLSocket class handles server_hostname encoding before it calls
    511     # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 512     return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    513         sock=sock,
    514         server_side=server_side,
    515         do_handshake_on_connect=do_handshake_on_connect,
    516         suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs,
    517         server_hostname=server_hostname,
    518         context=self,
    519         session=session
    520     )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py:1070, in SSLSocket._create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1069             raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1070         self.do_handshake()
   1071 except (OSError, ValueError):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py:1341, in SSLSocket.do_handshake(self, block)
   1340         self.settimeout(None)
-> 1341     self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1342 finally:

SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:789, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    788 # Make the request on the HTTPConnection object
--> 789 response = self._make_request(
    790     conn,
    791     method,
    792     url,
    793     timeout=timeout_obj,
    794     body=body,
    795     headers=headers,
    796     chunked=chunked,
    797     retries=retries,
    798     response_conn=response_conn,
    799     preload_content=preload_content,
    800     decode_content=decode_content,
    801     **response_kw,
    802 )
    804 # Everything went great!

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:490, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
    489         new_e = _wrap_proxy_error(new_e, conn.proxy.scheme)
--> 490     raise new_e
    492 # conn.request() calls http.client.*.request, not the method in
    493 # urllib3.request. It also calls makefile (recv) on the socket.

SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py:667, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    666 try:
--> 667     resp = conn.urlopen(
    668         method=request.method,
    669         url=url,
    670         body=request.body,
    671         headers=request.headers,
    672         redirect=False,
    673         assert_same_host=False,
    674         preload_content=False,
    675         decode_content=False,
    676         retries=self.max_retries,
    677         timeout=timeout,
    678         chunked=chunked,
    679     )
    681 except (ProtocolError, OSError) as err:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:843, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    841     new_e = ProtocolError("Connection aborted.", new_e)
--> 843 retries = retries.increment(
    844     method, url, error=new_e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    845 )
    846 retries.sleep()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py:519, in Retry.increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    518     reason = error or ResponseError(cause)
--> 519     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    521 log.debug("Incremented Retry for (url='%s'): %r", url, new_retry)

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.salesforce.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /services/Soap/u/59.0 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [57], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 s.verify = requests.certs.where()
      2 s.headers = headers
----> 3 resp = s.post(url)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py:637, in Session.post(self, url, data, json, **kwargs)
    626 def post(self, url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):
    627     r"""Sends a POST request. Returns :class:`Response` object.
    628 
    629     :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
   (...)
    634     :rtype: requests.Response
    635     """
--> 637     return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py:589, in Session.request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    584 send_kwargs = {
    585     "timeout": timeout,
    586     "allow_redirects": allow_redirects,
    587 }
    588 send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 589 resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    591 return resp

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py:703, in Session.send(self, request, **kwargs)
    700 start = preferred_clock()
    702 # Send the request
--> 703 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    705 # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
    706 elapsed = preferred_clock() - start

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py:698, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    694         raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
    696     if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    697         # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 698         raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    700     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    702 except ClosedPoolError as e:

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.salesforce.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /services/Soap/u/59.0 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)')))

I've also SSH'd into a separate machine and have been able to connect successfully. I'm unsure what my next course of action is. While my longer term plan is to migrate most of the extracts to golang as the distribution is simpler, python is a lot easier to work with in the exploratory stage, especially when I'm looking to run things locally rather than on a remote server.
